Content in resource of type Binary at path Binary.data is not appropriate for binary storage: base64Binary
Have an issue trying to store document as Binary with HAPI FHIR server starter (R4).
When i try to get my data with the operation GET fhir/Binary/logo/$binary-access-read?path=Binary.data , I receive this OperationOutcome error :
HAPI-1336: Content in resource of type Binary at path Binary.data is not appropriate for binary storage: base64Binary
My base64-encoded image isn't problematic, as I can decode it and obtain my image using my own code or online tools, so whats wrong ?
I tried to store it as a string instead, but I got the same issue HAPI-1336:..... path Binary.data is not appropriate for binary storage: string.
My content-type is well setted too; I can't get this Binary resource to work as described in FHIR doc !
Here is the json of my resource :
{
  "resourceType": "Binary",
  "id": "logo",
  "contentType": "image/png",
  "data" : "[my base64-encoded image (too long to post it there)]"
}

Here is my base64 string : https://file.io/K6HaZRRCAyEH
Thanks for any help
